# What is the best way to programmatically choose the best GPU in OpenCL?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu

On my laptop I have two graphic cards - Intel Iris and Nvidia GeForce GT 750M. I am trying to do a simple vector add using `OpenCL`. I know, that Nvidia card is much faster and can do the job better. In principle, I can put an `if` statement in the code that will look for `NVIDIA` in the `VENDOR` attribute. But I'd like to have something elegant. What is the best way to choose a better (faster) GPU programmatically in `OpenCL C/C++`?

Comment: Write a short benchmark, and test all available GPUs with this benchmark?

Comment: @arc_lupus overkill?

Comment: Overkill. Ok, what is the best way to choose NVIDIA card? Like I wrote, searching for the `VENDOR` attribute?

Comment: @bolov: What is the difference between the answer and a benchmark?

Comment: @arc_lupus for the OP's problem (to select programmatically the dedicated GPU from the integrated GPU for a *simple vector add*) I think that writing a application that does a benchmark  in order to determine on which GPU to run the simple vector add is overkill. Not to say that for the benchmark to have any relevant results, the time to run the benchmark might be longer than the difference between the add on the 2 cards (again, might). Even for a serious app integrating a benchmark into the app is overkill. What is wrong with a `select GPU: ` on first run or a config file? Just my opinion.

Comment: @bolov: Ok, for a simple vector addition that might be the case, but in the answer they are also doing a bench in order to determine which GPU to use...

Comment: Why not use both GPUs and the CPU as well? I did this with a ray tracer. I created a separate context for each device in a different thread. I had a two GTX580s and a Sandy Bridge processor. I had the GPUs render 45% and 45% and the CPU the last 10%. But actually I adjusted these numbers dynamically based on the previous frame. The cost to send memory between the CPU and GPU was negligible compared to the calculation (ray tracing is computationally intensive).  Though, for vector add it's memory bandwidth bound so using multiple devices probably won't help due to the data copying.

Comment: Even raytracing can be bottlenecked if you have low end motherboard and not compressing colors(such as using full 32 bit per pixel instead of compressing on the fly) with full-HD so FPS would be capped around 60-70. Of course  this is only for realtime version,.

Answer (score 6):

I developed a real-time ray tracer (not just a ray caster) which programmatically chose two GPUs and a CPU and rendered and balanced the load on all three in real time.  Here is how I did it.

Let's say there are three devices, `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`. Assign each device a weight: `w1`, `w2`, and `w3`. Call the number of pixels to be rendered `n`. Assume a free parameter called `alpha`.

1. Assign each device a weight of 1/3.
2. Let `alpha = 0.5`.
3. Render the first `n1=w1*n` pixels on `d1`, the next  `n2=w2*n` pixels on `d2`, and the last `n3=w3*n` pixels on `d3` and record the times to render for each deivce `t1`, `t2`, and `t3`.
4. Calculate a value `vsum = n1/t1 + n2/t2 + n3/t3`.
5. Recalcuate the weights `w_i = alpha*w_i + (1-alpha)*n_i/t_i/vsum`.
6. Go back to step 3.

The point of the value `alpha` is to allow a smooth transition. Instead of reassign all the weight based on the times it mixes in some of the old weight. Without using `alpha` I got instabilities. The value `alpha` can be tuned. In practice it can probably be set around 1% but not 0%.

---

Let's choose an example.

I had a GTX 590 which was a dual GPU card with two under-clocked GTX580s. I also had a Sandy Bridge 2600K processor.  The GPUs were much faster than the CPU.  Let's assume they were about 10 times faster. Let's also say there were 900 pixels.

Render the first 300 pixels with GPU1, the next 300 pixels with GPU2, and the last 300 pixels with CPU1 and record the times of `10 s, 10 s, and 100 s` respectively. So one GPU for the whole image would take 30 s and the CPU alone would take 300 s. Both GPUS together would take `15 s`.

Calculate `vsum = 30 + 30 + 3 = 63`. Recalculate the weights again: 
`w1,w2 = 0.5*(1/3) + 0.5*300/10/63 = 0.4` and `w3 = 0.5*(1/3) + 0.5*300/100/63 = 0.2`.

Render the next frame: 360 pixels with GPU1, 360 PIXELS with GPU2, and 180 PIXELS with CPU1 and the times become a bit more balanced say `11 s, 11 s, and 55 s`.

After a number of frames the `(1-alpha)` term dominates until eventually the weights are all based on that term. In this case the weights become 47% (427 pixels), 47%, 6% (46 pixels) respectively and the times become say `14 s, 14 s, 14 s` respectively.  In this case the CPU only improves the result of using only the GPUs by one second.

I assumed a uniform load in this calculate. In a real ray tracer the load varies per scan-line and pixel but the algorithm stays the same for determining the weights.

In practice once the weights are found they don't change much unless the load of the scene changes significantly e.g. if one region of the scene has high refraction and reflection and the rest is diffuse but even in this case I limit the tree depth so this does not have a dramatic effect.

It's easy to extend this method to multiple devices with a loop. I tested my ray tracer on four devices once. Two 12-core Xeon CPUs and two GPUs. In this case the CPUs had a lot more influence but the GPUs still dominated.

---

In case anyone is wondering. I created a context for each device and used each context in a separate thread (using pthreads). For three devices I used three threads.

In fact you can use this to run on the same device from different vendors. For example I used both the AMD and Intel CPU drivers simultaneously (each generating about half the frame) on my 2600K to see which vendor was better. When I first did this (2012), if I recall correctly,  AMD beat Intel, ironically, on an Intel CPU.

---

In case anyone is interested in how I came up with the formula for the weights I used an idea from physics (my background is physics not programming).

Speed (`v`) = distance/time. In this case distance (`d`) is the number of pixels to process. The total distance then is

```
d = v1*t1 + v2*t2 + v3*t3
```

and we want them to each finish in the same time so

```
d = (v1 + v2 + v3)*t
```

then to get the weight define

```
v_i*t = w_i*d
```

which gives

```
w_i = v_i*t/d
```

and replacing (`t/d`) from (`d = (v1 + v2 + v3)*t`) gives:

```
w_i = v_i /(v1 + v2 + v3)
```

It's easy to see this can be generalized to any number of devices `k`

```
w_i = v_i/(v1 + v2 + ...v_k)
```

So `vsum` in my algorithm stands for "sum of the velocities". Lastly since `v_i` is pixels over time it's `n_i/t_i` which finally gives

```
w_i = n_i/t_i/(n1/t1 + n2/t2 + ...n_k/t_k)
```

which is the second term in my formula to calculate the weights.

Comment: I created independent contexts to have explicit control too. This gives most performance. More threads decrease performance(after second command queue per device) since overhead of OS and kernel and some other thins stopped me doing a divide and conquer algortihm which should be most efficient for variable load map. I tried on java but did not try on C# yet. Fatter cores seem to be more advantegous though. GTX 680 barely get past a GTX 580 is this true?

Comment: I created seperate contexts on seperate threads because I could not get the Nvidia OpenCL drivers at the time (about two years ago with OpenCL 1.1) to run the separate devices with one thread. I read about using a context for each device in a seperate thread on a nvidia forum and it worked great. It only took an hour or two to get it working in pthreads even never having used pthreads. Pthreads was not as hard as people said. I even used pthreads in Windows at the time. Eventually, I moved it to SDL threads which are almost the same as pthreads.

Comment: I tried a 2D balancer but it still was going on a "line of tiles" instead of independent tiles(divided qonquered). Maybe HSA can help about this? Do you have a benchmark of that tracer? I like benchmarks :)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, no benchmark. I stopped working on it two years ago. I fixed it to run in Linux a year ago. It solved the tray tree, had reflection and refraction, HDR textures, solved the Fresnel equations. It look quite awesome. It was whitted style tracer. I could build some pretty cool objects with CSG and quadrics. Using quadrics was a lot faster than many triangles. But I only used floats so I had some float errors occasionally which I never fixed. I could probably fix that now.  Maybe I'll put it on github if you're interested. I can try and do tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: No thanks. Don't do that only for me. I tried scratchapixel's tracer to try balancing and it had only sphere-ray Fresnel  and later I tried building a static tree with triangles but I couldnt see my error in the triangle-ray intersection then I found a job and forgot about it.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I put a video of my real-time ray-tracer on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GErl-poxmNE

Comment: @Z boson Nice work. Did you use fake recursivity or something like iterative technique for refractions? Which device is it? Multi device? Ok, I just saw GTX580. Ray depth?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I created a queue for each pixel and pushed rays onto the queue, up to two per interaction, then I process them one at a tim. The depth is a parameter I think I usually use a depth of 20.

The ray tracer works for multiple devices but when I made the video for youtube I actually used a GTX980M on my laptop because that's what I had Camtasia on so I guess saying I used a GTX580 is misleading. Actually I developed most of this on a GTX590 3+ years ago. Then I discovered SO and stopped doing useful things in my personal time.

Answer (score 3):

If it is simply a vector add and your app resides in host-side then cpu will win. Or even better, integrated cpu will be much faster. Overall performance depends on algortihms, opencl buffer types(use_host_ptr, read_write, etc) and compute to data ratio. Even if you dont copy but pin the array and access, cpu's latency would be smaller than pci-e latency.

If you are going to use opengl + opencl interop, then you will need to know if your compute device is the same device with your rendering output device. (if your screen gets its data from igpu then it is iris, if not then it is nvidia)

If you just need to do some operations on c++ arrays(host side) and get results with fastest way then I suggest you the "load balancing".

Example of vector-add of 4k elements on a Core i7-5775C with Iris pro and two gt750m (one overclocked by 10%)

First, give equal number of ndrange rages to all devices. At the end of each calculation phase, check timings.

```
CPU      iGPU        dGPU-1        dGPU-2 oc
Intel    Intel       Nvidia        Nvidia  
1024     1024        1024          1024  
34 ms    5ms         10ms          9ms
```

then calculate weighted(depends on last ndrange range) but relaxed(not exact but close) approximations of calculation bandwidths and change ndrange ranges accordingly:

```
Intel    Intel       Nvidia        Nvidia 
512      1536        1024          1024  
16 ms    8ms         10ms          9ms
```

then continue calculating until it really becomes stable.

```
Intel    Intel       Nvidia        Nvidia 
256      1792        1024          1024  
9ms      10ms         10ms         9ms
```

or until you can enable finer grains.

```
Intel    Intel       Nvidia        Nvidia 
320      1728        1024          1024  
10ms     10ms        10ms          9ms 

Intel    Intel       Nvidia        Nvidia  
320      1728        960           1088  
10ms     10ms        10ms          10ms 

         ^            ^
         |            |
         |            PCI-E bandwidth not more than 16 GB/s per device
        closer to RAM, better bandwidth (20-40 GB/s) and less kernel overhead
```

Instead of getting just the latest iteration for balancing, you can get average(or PID) of last 10 results to eliminate spikes that mislead balancing. Also buffer copies can take more time than computing, if you include this into balancing, you can shut down unnecessary / non benefiting devices.

If you make a library, then you wont have to try benchmark for every new project of yours. They will be auto balanced between devices when you accelerate matrix multiplications, fluid movements, sql table joins and financial approximations.

For the solution of balancing:

If you can solve a linear system as n unknowns(of loads per device) and n equations (benchmark result of all devices), you can find the target loads in single step. If you choose iterative, you need more steps until it converges. The latter is not harder than writing a benchmark. The former is harder for me but it should be more efficient over time.

Althogh a vector-add-only kernel is not a real world scenario, here is a real benchmark from my system:

```
 __kernel void bench(__global float * a, __global float *b, __global float *c)
                {
                    int i=get_global_id(0);
                    c[i]=a[i]+b[i];  
                }
2560   768 768
AMD FX(tm)-8150 Eight-Core Processor            Oland Pitcairn
```

this is after several iterations(fx is faster even with extra buffer copies, not using any host pointer). Even the oland gpu is catching pitcairn because their pci-e bandwidth is same.

Now with some trigonometric functions:

```
  __kernel void bench(__global float * a, __global float *b, __global float *c)
  {
        int i=get_global_id(0);
        c[i]=sin(a[i])+cos(b[i])+sin(cos((float)i));  
  }

   1792   1024 1280
```

testing gddr3-128bit vs gddr5-256bit(overclocked) and caching.

```
__kernel void bench(__global float * a, __global float *b, __global float *c)
{
                    int i=get_global_id(0);

                    c[i]=a[i]+b[i]-a[i]-b[i]+a[i]+b[i]-b[i]-a[i]+b[i]; 
                    for(int j=0;j<12000;j++)
                        c[i]+=a[i]+b[i]-a[i]-b[i]+a[i]+b[i]-b[i]-a[i]+b[i]; 

 }



 256   256 3584
```

High compute to data ratio :

```
__kernel void bench(__global float * a, __global float *b, __global float *c)
            {
                int i=get_global_id(0);

                c[i]=0.0f; float c0=c[i];float a0=a[i];float b0=b[i];
                for(int j=0;j<12000;j++)
                    c0+=sin(a0)+cos(b0*a0)+cos(sin(b0)*19.95f); 
                c[i]=c0;

            }

256   2048 1792
```

Now Oland gpu is worthy again and won even with just 320 cores. Because 4k elements easily wrapped around all 320 cores for more than 10 times but pitcairn gpu(1280 cores) was not fully filled with folded arrays (wavefronts) enough and this led to lower occupation of execution units ---> could not hide latencies.
Low end devices for low loads is better I think. Maybe I could use this when directx-12 comes out with some loadbalancer and this Oland can compute physics of 5000 - 10000 particles from in game explosions while pitcairn can compute smoke densities.

Comment: "If it is simply a vector add and your app resides in host-side then cpu will win."What do you mean by that? I am coming from CUDA programming, and vector add on the same graphic card (GT 750) using CUDA was almost always faster than CPU.

Comment: If it is purely in gpu then yes. But if results are copied to host, then not. Because host side computing doesnt need extra copying.

Comment: No, I still don't understand. Copying to and from host is also involved in CUDA...

Comment: Unless you are pinning the buffers or have a NV-Link system, it is bottlenecked by pcie-bandwidth. Are you pinning buffers before using them(without copying) Or are you using them at least tens of times before copying back to host? Even my slow amd fx cpu is summing an array much faster than my 50x faster gpu.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. If I load the GPU more with computations, then the bandwidth becomes less important. Thanks

Comment: I just posted an answer without reading yours carefully. Our methods seem to be quite similar.

Answer (score 3):

**Good:** Just pick the first compatible device. On most systems, there is only one.

**Better:** You can *very roughly* estimate device performance by multiplying the CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS device info result by the CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY device info result. Depending on your workload, you might want to include other metrics such as memory size. You could blend these based on what your workload is.

**Best:** Benchmark with your exact workflow on each device. It's really the only way to know for sure, since anything else is just a guess.

Finally, the user might care about which of their GPUs you are using, so you should have some way to override your programmatic choice regardless of which method you choose.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this code for GPU discrimination:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "x86_64/opencl.lib")
#endif

//OpenCL saxpy kernel used for benchmarking
const char* saxpy_kernel =
"__kernel                                    \n"
"void saxpy_kernel(float alpha,              \n"
"                  __global float *A,        \n"
"                  __global float *B,        \n"
"                  __global float *C)        \n"
"{                                           \n"
"    int idx = get_global_id(0);             \n"
"    C[idx] = alpha * A[idx] + B[idx];       \n"
"}                                           ";

const char* clErrName[] = {
    "CL_SUCCESS",                                   //0
    "CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND",                          //-1
    "CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE",                      //-2
    "CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE",                    //-3
    "CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE",             //-4
    "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES",                          //-5
    "CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY",                        //-6
    "CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE",              //-7
    "CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP",                          //-8
    "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH",                     //-9
    "CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED",                //-10
    "CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE",                     //-11
    "CL_MAP_FAILURE",                               //-12
    "CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET",              //-13
    "CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST", //-14
    "CL_COMPILE_PROGRAM_FAILURE",                   //-15
    "CL_LINKER_NOT_AVAILABLE",                      //-16
    "CL_LINK_PROGRAM_FAILURE",                      //-17
    "CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_FAILED",                   //-18
    "CL_KERNEL_ARG_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE",             //-19

    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_20",                        //-20
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_21",                        //-21
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_22",                        //-22
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_23",                        //-23
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_24",                        //-24
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_25",                        //-25
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_26",                        //-26
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_27",                        //-27
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_28",                        //-28
    "CL_UNDEFINED_ERROR_29",                        //-29

    "CL_INVALID_VALUE",                             //-30
    "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE",                       //-31
    "CL_INVALID_PLATFORM",                          //-32
    "CL_INVALID_DEVICE",                            //-33
    "CL_INVALID_CONTEXT",                           //-34
    "CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES",                  //-35
    "CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE",                     //-36
    "CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR",                          //-37
    "CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT",                        //-38
    "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR",           //-39
    "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE",                        //-40
    "CL_INVALID_SAMPLER",                           //-41
    "CL_INVALID_BINARY",                            //-42
    "CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS",                     //-43
    "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM",                           //-44
    "CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE",                //-45
    "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME",                       //-46
    "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION",                 //-47
    "CL_INVALID_KERNEL",                            //-48
    "CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX",                         //-49
    "CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE",                         //-50
    "CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE",                          //-51
    "CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS",                       //-52
    "CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION",                    //-53
    "CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE",                   //-54
    "CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE",                    //-55
    "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET",                     //-56
    "CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST",                   //-57
    "CL_INVALID_EVENT",                             //-58
    "CL_INVALID_OPERATION",                         //-59
    "CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT",                         //-60
    "CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE",                       //-61
    "CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL",                         //-62
    "CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE",                  //-63
    "CL_INVALID_PROPERTY",                          //-64
    "CL_INVALID_IMAGE_DESCRIPTOR",                  //-65
    "CL_INVALID_COMPILER_OPTIONS",                  //-66
    "CL_INVALID_LINKER_OPTIONS",                    //-67
    "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_PARTITION_COUNT",            //-68
    "CL_INVALID_PIPE_SIZE",                         //-69
    "CL_INVALID_DEVICE_QUEUE",                      //-70
};
 const int MAX_ERR_CODE = 70;

inline bool __clCallSuccess(cl_int err_code, const char* source_file, const int source_line)
{
    if (err_code == CL_SUCCESS)
        return true;

    if ((err_code > 0) || (err_code < -MAX_ERR_CODE))
        std::clog << "\t - unknown CL error: " << err_code;
    else
        std::clog << "\t - CL call error: " << clErrName[-err_code];

    std::clog << " [" << source_file << " : " << source_line << "]" << std::endl;

    return false;
}

#define clCallSuccess(err_code) __clCallSuccess(err_code, __FILE__, __LINE__)

float cl_BenchmarkDevice(cl_context context, cl_command_queue command_queue, cl_device_id device_id)
{
    float microSeconds = -1.;
    int i;
    cl_int clStatus;

    const int VECTOR_SIZE = 512 * 1024;
    // Allocate space for vectors A, B and C
    float* A = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * VECTOR_SIZE);         if(A) {
    float* B = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * VECTOR_SIZE);         if(B) {
    float* C = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * VECTOR_SIZE);         if(C) {
    for (i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        A[i] = (float)i;
        B[i] = (float)(VECTOR_SIZE - i);
        C[i] = 0;
    }

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector
    cl_mem A_clmem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(float), NULL, &clStatus);   if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    cl_mem B_clmem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(float), NULL, &clStatus);   if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    cl_mem C_clmem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(float), NULL, &clStatus);  if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {

    // Copy the Buffer A and B to the device
    clStatus = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, A_clmem, CL_TRUE, 0, VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(float), A, 0, NULL, NULL); if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    clStatus = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, B_clmem, CL_TRUE, 0, VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(float), B, 0, NULL, NULL); if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {

    // Create a program from the kernel source and build it
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&saxpy_kernel, NULL, &clStatus);   if (clCallSuccess(clStatus) && program) {
    clStatus = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);                                        if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "saxpy_kernel", &clStatus);                  if (clCallSuccess(clStatus) && kernel) {

    float alpha = 2.5;
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    clStatus = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(float), (void*)&alpha);                     if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    clStatus = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&A_clmem);                  if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    clStatus = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&B_clmem);                  if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    clStatus = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&C_clmem);                  if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    cl_event event;
    size_t global_size = VECTOR_SIZE; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_size = 512;           // Process one item at a time
    //clStatus = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_size, &local_size, 0, NULL, &event);
    clStatus = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);                 if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    clStatus = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);                                                                                  if (clCallSuccess(clStatus)) {
    //measure duration
    cl_ulong time_start;
    cl_ulong time_end;
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
    microSeconds = (float)(time_end - time_start) / 1000.0f;
    std::clog << "\nOpenCl benchmarking time: " << microSeconds << " microseconds \n";

    std::clog << "\n\t*****************************\n\n";
    }
    // Read the cl memory C_clmem on device to the host variable C
    clCallSuccess(clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, C_clmem, CL_TRUE, 0, VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(float), C, 0, NULL, NULL));

    // Clean up and wait for all the comands to complete.
    clCallSuccess(clFlush(command_queue));
    clCallSuccess(clFinish(command_queue));


    } //Kernel

    }}}} //SetKErnelArg

    // Finally release all OpenCL allocated objects and host buffers.

    clCallSuccess(clReleaseKernel(kernel)); }

    } //BuildProgram

    clCallSuccess(clReleaseProgram(program)); }

    } } //EnqueueWriteBuffer

    clCallSuccess(clReleaseMemObject(C_clmem)); } 
    clCallSuccess(clReleaseMemObject(B_clmem)); } 
    clCallSuccess(clReleaseMemObject(A_clmem)); }

    free(C); } 
    free(B); } 
    free(A); }

    return microSeconds;
}

/*
struct _dev_info {
    cl_platform_id platfID;
    cl_device_id devID;
};
typedef struct _dev_info dev_info;
*/
cl_device_id cl_GetBestDevice(void)
{
    cl_int err;
    cl_uint numPlatforms, numDevices;
    cl_platform_id platfIDs[10];
    cl_device_id devIDsAll[10];
    int countGPUs = 0;
    cl_device_id best_device = NULL;
    float best_perf = 100000000.;

    if (clCallSuccess(clGetPlatformIDs(10, platfIDs, &numPlatforms))) 
    {
        std::clog << "OpenCL platforms detected: " << numPlatforms << std::endl;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numPlatforms; i++) 
        {
            std::clog << "PlatformInfo for platform no." << (i + 1) << std::endl;

            const int SZ_INFO = 1024;
            char info[SZ_INFO];
            size_t sz;
            if (clCallSuccess(clGetPlatformInfo(platfIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                std::clog << " - - Name: " << info << std::endl;
            if (clCallSuccess(clGetPlatformInfo(platfIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                std::clog << " - - Vendor: " << info << std::endl;
            if (clCallSuccess(clGetPlatformInfo(platfIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                std::clog << " - - Profile: " << info << std::endl;
            if (clCallSuccess(clGetPlatformInfo(platfIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                std::clog << " - - Version: " << info << std::endl;
            if (clCallSuccess(clGetPlatformInfo(platfIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                std::clog << " - - Extensions: " << info << std::endl;

            if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceIDs(platfIDs[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 10, devIDsAll, &numDevices))) 
            {
                cl_context_properties cProperties[] = { CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platfIDs[i]), 0 };
                cl_command_queue_properties qProperties[] = { CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, 0 };

                for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < numDevices; ii++)
                {
                    cl_uint val;
                    cl_ulong memsz;
                    cl_device_type dt;
                    size_t mws;

                    std::clog << " >> DeviceInfo for device no." << (ii + 1) << std::endl;

                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_NAME, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Name: " << info << std::endl;
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Vendor: " << info << std::endl;
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_VERSION, SZ_INFO, info, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Version: " << info << std::endl;
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_TYPE, sizeof(dt), &dt, &sz)))
                    {
                        std::clog << "\t - Type: ";
                        switch (dt)
                        {
                            case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU: std::clog << "CPU"; break;
                            case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU: std::clog << "GPU"; break;
                            case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR: std::clog << "Accelerator"; break;
                            case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT: std::clog << "Default"; break;
                            default: std::clog << "ERROR";
                        }
                        std::clog << std::endl;
                    }
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(memsz), &memsz, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Memory: " << (memsz / 1024 / 1024) << " MB" << std::endl;
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(val), &val, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Max Frequency: " << val << " MHz" << std::endl;
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(val), &val, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Compute units: " << val << std::endl;
                    if (clCallSuccess(clGetDeviceInfo(devIDsAll[ii], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(mws), &mws, &sz)))
                        std::clog << "\t - Max workgroup size: " << mws << std::endl;

                    // Create an OpenCL context
                    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, devIDsAll+ii, NULL, NULL, &err);
                    if (clCallSuccess(err) && context)
                    {
                        // Create a command queue
                        cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, devIDsAll[ii], qProperties, &err);
                        if (clCallSuccess(err) && command_queue)
                        {
                            float perf = cl_BenchmarkDevice(context, command_queue, devIDsAll[ii]);
                            if ((perf > 0) && (perf < best_perf)) 
                            {
                                best_perf = perf;
                                best_device = devIDsAll[ii];
                            }

                            clCallSuccess(clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue));
                        }
                        clCallSuccess(clReleaseContext(context));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return best_device;
}
```

[here is the output on my PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LTQO.png)